# Javascript - replacing link values after inputting data into textbox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am new to javascript, and as far I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#Login').keyup('href', function () {
       return $('#checkUserName').replace('__userName__', $('#Login').val());
   });
</script>
```

Now, that code was supposed to replace #checkUserName link's value after inputting data in #Login input. But it doesn't. What is wrong in here?

Comment: What type of element is checkUserName?

Comment: Also, I don't believe .keyup() takes two parameters.  You have 'href' and a function for your two params...

Comment: jQuery elements don't have a `.replace` method. You probably want to access a specific attribute or property with `.attr` or `.prop`.

Answer (score 1):

how about using java script only you have an onlcick or on change or some kind of change event

```
function myFunction()
{
      var str=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
      var n=str.replace("Microsoft","W3Schools");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to access the `href` attribute through `.attr()`, instead of putting it before the function definition in `keyup` (which I think is illegal):

```
$('#Login').keyup(function () {
   $('#checkUserName').attr('href', $('#Login').val());
});
```

Also, there is no need for the `return` call.